# Safe convertion/casting from uint256 to int256

Tags: gas, chainlink, type-casting

I have a small function `getConversionRate`() that converts a value in ETH to USD using `AggregatorV3Interface.latestRoundData()`. Here `priceFeed` is a implementation of  `AggregatorV3Interface` using chainlink pointing to rinkeby ETH/USD at address `0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e` (from here https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/ ).

```
    function getConversionRate(int256 amount) public view returns (int256) {
        (,int256 price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

        // Fetch decimals
        uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();

        // Normalize to 18 decimal places (aka converting to WEI)
        price = price * int256(10 ** (18 - decimals));

        // In wei
        int256 weiAmountInUsd = price * amount;

        // In ETH
        int256 ethAmountInUsd = weiAmountInUsd / (10 ** 18);

        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
```

This function was kept using `int256` just because it can be also used to convert both, positive or negative values.

Then I try to use this `getConvertionRate()` with `msg.value` that seems be `uint256`.

```
    function fund() public payable {
        int256 minimumUSD = 50;
        int256 minimumETH = minimumUSD * 10 ** 18;
        // Hidden bug HERE uint256 -> int256
        require(getConversionRate(int256(msg.value)) >= minimumETH);
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
```

There is a hidden bug here, since, if `msg.value` is in upper half of `int256`. The value will be converted to negative integers. (and I don't want that).

My question is, how to handle this case?

Parallel question: I did some handling for the decimal places in values returned from the aggregator using the `decimals()` function. IS that TOO convolute/expensive? Should I trust always to have the same amount of decimals and hardcode the convertion decimal places? What are the main drawbacks in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(msg.value <= 0x7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff) // or type(uint256).max/2
```

would work. Its unlikely someone try to send more than 5.7*10^58 ETH to your contract though x)

Comment: To address your other question, i would keep using `decimals()`, most tokens have 18 decimals but you never know